# Exibir uma mensagem na saída do comando

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou executando esta PL/SQL e caso a condição caia no `else`, como mostrar a mensagem para o usuário?

```
declare
  cont integer;
  tabela varchar2(100) := 'PESSOA';
  coluna varchar2(100) := 'NOME';
begin
    SELECT COUNT(NOME) into cont FROM PESSOA;
   if cont = 0 then
       execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||tabela||' DROP COLUMN '||coluna||'';
       commit;
   else
       ('Coluna '||coluna||'não excluído porque contém Dados');
   end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Mas como isso vai ser utilizado? É uma procedure? Ou você quer apenas mostrar no console?

Comment: Estou executando vários blocos como este (Criaçaõ de campos). Neste em específico gostaria que exibisse no console. Ou seja, caso cair no else, ele exibe a mensagem no console e continua executando os outros blocos normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir no console é só usar o `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line`:

```
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Minha mensagem');
end;
```

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
declare
  cont integer;
  tabela varchar2(100) := 'PESSOA';
  coluna varchar2(100) := 'NOME';
begin
    SELECT COUNT(NOME) into cont FROM PESSOA;
   if cont = 0 then
       execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||tabela||' DROP COLUMN '||coluna||'';
       commit;
   else
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Coluna '||coluna||'não excluído porque contém Dados');
   end if;
end;
```

Para ver o output no SQL Developer vá em: **View -> DBMS Output**

Comment: Precisa colocar outro begin no else ?

Comment: @Douglas, não. Inclui com seu código na resposta.

Comment: Deu essa mensagem que já é a padrão: [2018-12-13 10:28:54] completed in 33 ms. Mas não exibiu a personalizada.

Comment: @Douglas você tem que conferir a saída (Output) que IDE você utiliza? SQL Developer?

Comment: Estou olhando a saída mesmo, estou usando o DataGrip.

Comment: @Douglas, não conheço o DataGrip mas se vc está olhando o output mesmo e não aparece a mensagem é por que ele não caiu no else. Faça um teste colocando outra mensagem no if só pra ver se aparece.

Comment: Mesma coisa, testei no SQL Developer e exibe a mensagem padrão: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: @Douglas, veja se isso te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887413/printing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-developer

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87029/discussion-between-george-wurthmann-and-douglas).

Comment: Obrigado, era configuração da ferramenta, agora funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Como a mensagem e referente à um erro, é possível utilizar o método [Raise_application_error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm), que vai interromper a execução do procedimento PLSQL e vai levantar uma exceção para a aplicação que esta conectada ao banco.

Comment: +1 como ele não especificou na pergunta que o código deveria continuar após a mensagem, a resposta também é válida. Mas seria interessante um exemplo com o código da pergunta dele.